# How can I save my tab session, even if it is a form which I was filling, avoid loosing my text?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am filling a form in one firefox tab. But now I have to close the browser and/or the computer and I don't want to loose what I've written.

Is there a way to store that tabs session and restore it later as if I've never closed the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Theres this addon which works awesome: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it looks more of a question about using Firefox rather than writing a Firefox add-on to perform this task. Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

To perform what is basically what you are describing I use a combination of two different Firefox add-ons:

1. [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/): This will restore Firefox sessions (tabs). If I recall correctly, this usually includs data entered in forms. In addition to restoring crashed sessions, it allows you to select which session to restore from any which you have previously saved (automatically or manually saved).
2. [Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/): This caches larger text area entries for multiple pages. It can be used to recover longer text areas where you have edited the contents of a text box entry (e.g. the contents of textboxes such as the one in which I am writing this answer).